# jclouds set bucket-owner-full-control acl

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

Using the jclouds library, how can one specify the **bucket-owner-full-control** canned acl when putting an object to amazon s3 e.g. `blobStore.putBlob(containerName, blob)`. The [CannedAccessPolicy](https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/1.8.x/org/jclouds/s3/domain/CannedAccessPolicy.html) class doesn't seem to have all the options as per the amazon s3 documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

Just to note that this is with jclouds 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable `BlobStore` interface cannot offer all the functionality of providers.  Instead you should use the underlying provider interface, `S3Client` and `putObject` with the correct `CannedAccessPolicy`.  As you point out, in jclouds 2.0.3 this class lacks some of the constants and 2.1.0 will include a fix for this issue.

Comment: OK. I've created an issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1370. I don't know the code well enough to submit a pull request.